# Eager load hasMany & belongsTo (circular reference/infinite loop)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

- If you need `->user` relationship from one of the `$image` inside `$user->images`, then `$user` variable is already available cause you loaded the `->images` from it!
- Don't use `protected $with` Eloquent property. It's an anti-pattern.
- Instead explicitly eager load relationships on-demand from where/when it's needed (*Note*: it should not prevent you to keep things DRY!)
- If you really need/want to, see @nicksonyap answer. It does the trick (I believe – not tested).

**ORIGINAL**

I'm running into what I believe is a simple problem:

- I have a `User` object that *has many* `Image`s
- `Image` *belongs to* `User`... (inverse relation)

My problem is that I want to eager load both the `images()` on the `User` model and the `user()` on the `Image` model. To do so, I just setup a `$with` property as explained in the docs.

My `User` model:

```php
class User extends EloquentModel {
    protected $with = ['images'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

My `Image` model:

```php
class Image extends EloquentModel {
    protected $with = ['user'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

But when performing:

```php
$user = User::find(203);
```

This results in an infinite loop (php segmentation fault). There must be some kind of circular reference that I am not able to locate:

```
[1]    85728 segmentation fault
```

**EDIT 2016/02**

This is the simplest "Workaround" I found:

```php
// User.php
public function setRelation($relation, $value)
{
    if ($relation === 'images') {
        foreach ($value as $image) {
            $image->setUser($this);
        }
    }
    return parent::setRelation($relation, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a `without()` method: https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_without

Placing `without()` on both sides of a relationship worked.

```php
class Property extends EloquentModel {
    protected $with = ['images'];

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class)->without('property');
    }
}
```

```php
class Image extends EloquentModel {
    protected $with = ['property'];

    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Property::class)->without('images');
    }

    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->property->title;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Even though using `without()` easily avoid the infinite loop issue, through years of experience with Laravel I realize it is bad practice to set `$with` in the model as it causes relationships to always load. Hence leading to circular reference/infinite loop

Rather, **always use `with()` to explicitly specify** necessary relationships to be eager loaded, however deep necessary (relationship of relationship)

For example:

```php
$user = User::with('images' => function ($query) {
            $query->with('property' => function ($query) {
                $query->with('deeperifneeded' => function ($query) {
                    //...
                });
            });
        ]);
```

Note: May need to remove `without()`

Comment: That could work. I accepted your answer (~3 years later...), although I would advise against it in favor of explicitness (see my update).

Answer (score 1):

When you try to find a Property, that property eager loads all the images it has and every Image eager loads the property it belongs to, which is the property you try to find, which will again start to eager load all the images it has. etc...

The way I would resolve this problem is by not eager loading inside the models, but by eager loading when calling the models.

so using  the following:

```
$prop = Property::with('images')->find(203);
```

while removing this line in the Property model:

```
protected $with = ['images'];
```

And this line in the Image model:

```
protected $with = ['property'];
```

I hope this solution works for you.

Comment: Hi, thx. I feel you, I'm just surprised there is no built-in way to handle that case in Eloquent. From my understanding that would be as easy as when `Property` receives `images` relationship, then for each image `->setRelation('property', $this)`. Instead of re-asking the same Property to the ORM, etc, etc... I'm surprised there is nothing preventing you to avoid that infinite Loop (error message???)