# Laravel routing with model as string with eager loading - Circular Reference

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to simplify my routing for my models using Laravel 5.1. I have two resources, Questions and Categories, which inherit from `ResourceController`.

```
$router->get('/categories', 'Resources\Categories@index');
$router->get('/questions', 'Resources\Questions@index');
```

In `ResourceController.php`, my resource classes use this `index` method:

```
public function index(Request $request, Route $route)
{
    // Converts route name into namespaced Model string
    // E.g: App\Http\Controllers\Resources\Questions@index -> App\Question
    $model = $this->getModelClass($route->getActionName());

    return $model::all();
}
```

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409665/call-laravel-model-by-string) says I can call a eloquent methods using a fully qualified string:

```
$model_name = 'App\Model\User';
$model_name::where('id', $id)->first();
```

If I return `$model`, I get `App\Category` and `App\Question` for the respective routes I hit. This is good!

If I return `$model::all()`, I get a **500 error** with no data.

I checked my sequel pro query logger and saw that both `questions` and `categories` were called about 20+ times even though I'm making a request to only one route at a time.

[image]

Why is this happening? This could explain the 500 error. I was able to get the models when only one resource was using this parent `index` method.

When both `Questions` and `Categories` relied on the same `index`, the errors started. I don't see why this is a conflict as the route sends the specific call to the index with the model name.

---

**EDIT**: I think this is related to how I am specifying eager loading:

`Category.php` Model:

```
protected $with = ['questions'];
```

`Question.php` Model:

```
protected $with = ['category'];
```

So it seems to be a circular reference where loading questions will come with categories, which will in turn load related questions, and so on.

But I do in fact need each to load with the relation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995187/eager-load-hasmany-belongsto-circular-reference-infinite-loop).

It indeed seems to be a circular reference. Eager loads should happen on the query, not on the model if you want a generic model loader:

In my models, I changed the `$with` to a constant which I can load myself:

```
class Category extends BaseModel
{
    // Removed: protected $with = ['questions'];
    const EAGER_LOAD = ['questions'];
```

In the parent resource controller, I load the constants here:

```
public function index(Request $request, Route $route)
{
    $model = $this->getModelClass($route->getActionName());

    return $model->with($model::EAGER_LOAD)->get();
}
```